# ActiveRecord is not reloading nested object after it's updated inside a transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, transactions

I'm using Rails 4 with Oracle 12c and I need to update the status of an User, and then use the new status in a validation for another model I also need to update:

```
class User
  has_many :posts

  def custom_update!(new_status)
    relevant_posts = user.posts.active_or_something
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      update!(status: new_status)
      relevant_posts.each { |post| post.update_stuff! }
    end
  end
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user

  validate :pesky_validation

  def update_stuff!
    # I can call this from other places, so I also need a transaction here
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      update!(some_stuff: 'Some Value')
    end
  end

  def pesky_validation
    if user.status == OLD_STATUS
      errors.add(:base, 'Nope')
    end
  end
end
```

However, this is failing and I receive the validation error from `pesky_validation`, because the user inside Post doesn't have the updated status.

The problem is, when I first update the user, the already instantiated users inside the `relevant_posts` variable are not yet updated, and normally all I'd need to fix this was to call `reload`, however, maybe because I'm inside a transaction, this is not working, and `pesky_validation` is failing.

`relevant_users.first.user.reload`, for example, reloads the user to the same old status it had before the update, and I'm assuming it's because the transaction is not yet committed. How can I solve this and update all references to the new status?

Comment: You assume the transaction is not committed, but what about the server log. We should check the server log and see the `sql` statements before and after you perform that reload and the other transactions

Comment: The server logs doesn't show the transaction being committed, and this shouldn't be possible anyway because I'm still inside it when I'm trying to do this validation.

Comment: the server log does not show sql?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't show anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Besides, I'm ashamed to admit that I've found the cause, and it's not a weird bug in Rails or AR. It was in fact an obscure legacy piece of code triggered by an observer that was changing the status back to its previous value. Thanks for trying to help.